# Substrings of a string using Python

Tags: python, string, substring

How many [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) can you make out of a string like `abcd`?

How can I get all of its substrings:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

Comment: You are asking two different questions: "How many combinations can you make…?" and, "How can I get it to look like…". The answers to those two questions are very different.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I don't see how that's true. One is just the length of the other. You can make `sum(1...n)`, i.e. `n*n(-1)/2` [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) of a string of length `n`.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
def consecutive_groups(iterable):
    s = tuple(iterable)
    for size in range(1, len(s)+1):
        for index in range(len(s)+1-size):
            yield iterable[index:index+size]

>>> print list(consecutive_groups('abcd'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

And the number of combinations is simply equal to the sum from 1 to the length of the string, which is equivalent to `n * (n + 1) / 2`.

By the way, if you want to avoid duplicates, you can simply use a locally-defined set in the generator function, like so:

```
def consecutive_groups(iterable):
    s = tuple(iterable)
    seen = set()
    for size in range(1, len(s)+1):
        for index in range(len(s)+1-size):
            slc = iterable[index:index+size]
            if slc not in seen:
                seen.add(slc)
                yield slc
```

That code is a little more unwieldy and could probably be optimized for indentation, but it will do for a proof of concept.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but it's not quite right.  Try `map(partial(reduce, operator.add), powerset('abcd'))`.

Comment: generators make hulk happy! +1 O.o

Comment: I just noticed this is a fine approach as long as the OP doesn't care for duplicated substrings. (e.g. what happens with `'abcdab'`)

Comment: Good point @madth3: while the OP never specified either way, I have provided a version of the generator that keeps track of what has been seen.

Comment: either `n` or `n + 1` are even, so a division by 2 will always yield an integer result. What do you mean with the comment about the true division?

Comment: @hochl Nothing, brain lapse. (I probably was mistakenly thinking that the division would be evaluated first, before the multiplication.) Editing.

Answer (score 11):

Would this do?

```
import itertools
def substrings(x):
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(xrange(len(x)+1), 2):
        yield x[i:j]
```

or as generator expression:

```
(x[i:j] for i, j in itertools.combinations(xrange(len(x)+1), 2))
```

The expanded result for your example looks like this:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```

To order by length, use sort `key=len`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
In [260]: S = 'abcd'

In [261]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(itertools.combinations(S,i)) for i in range(1,len(S))]))
Out[261]: 
[('a',),
 ('b',),
 ('c',),
 ('d',),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Or if you really want them all as strings, you could do:

```
In [262]: combos  = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(itertools.combinations(S,i)) for i in range(1,len(S))]))

In [263]: [''.join(c) for c in combos]
Out[263]: 
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'bc',
 'bd',
 'cd',
 'abc',
 'abd',
 'acd',
 'bcd']
```

**EDIT To get only substrings of `S`**:

```
In [270]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[S[i:i+k] for i in range(len(S)-k)] for k in range(1,len(S)+1)])) + [S]
Out[270]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'bc', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Comment: I think you want `itertools.combinations(S, i+1)`, to get the unchanged string too. Also the `list` and square brackets around your inner generator are unnecessary. `chain.from_iterable` is perfectly happy taking generators from a generator.

Comment: is the empty string part of a solution? If yes you are missing it too. I think `ac` is not a valid solution either since `b` is missing in between.

Comment: for the second one (EDIT To get only substrings of S:) how would I find only substrings of length x?

Comment: @Mathime: You should be able to filter them after the fact: `answer = [s for s in all_substrings if len(s) == x]`

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions there.

The first, `How many substrings can you make out of a string like “abcd”?` is a combinations like this:

```
import itertools
s='abcd'
com=[list(itertools.combinations(s,x)) for x in range(1,len(s)+1)]

print [''.join(e) for e in sum(com,[])]
```

prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

**The second question is how to replicate your example (which is not a 'combination').** You can do that with this code:

```
>>> [s[i:i+j] for j in range(1,len(s)+1) for i in range(len(s)-j+1)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

Comment: I did not downvote but most probably because `ac` is not part of the solution.

Comment: actually `ac` still is not a substring because `a` and `c` are not *neighbours* to each other.

Comment: @hochl: Please look at the edit. It produces his example exactly. The problem is he is asking two questions.

Comment: if `ac` is a substring then quite possibly `ca` is a substring too since `a` and `c` are part of the string. I think he means a substring consists of consecutive ranges of characters.

Comment: @hochl: Please look at the second list. It addresses your comments. `ac` is not part of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']`  It replicates the example exactly.

Comment: To understand the downvotes, see the meaning of a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring). No one asked for the combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works too and while is not the most efficient, it has the attractive of using less complex features.

```
S = "abcd"
substrings = [S[i:j] for i in range(len(S)) for j in range(i+1,len(S)+1)]
substrings.sort(key=len)
```

Note however that this approach does not remove identical substrings that might appear. For example if the original substring was `"abcdab"`, `a`, `b` and `ab` would appear twice.

Comment: In order to not include duplicate substrings, change the list comprehension `[...]` to a set comprehension `{...}`.