# Find longest palindromic substring using Rabin-Karp algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, rabin-karp

From https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/

> **15. Longest palindromic substring**. Given a string s, find the longest
> substring that is a palindrome (or a Watson-crick palindrome).
>
> **Solution**: can be solved in linear time using suffix trees or
> Manacher's algorithm. Here's a simpler solution that typically runs in
> linearthmic time. First, we describe how to find all palindromic
> substrings of length exactly L in linear time: use Karp-Rabin to
> iteratively form the hashes of each substring of length L (and its
> reverse), and compare. Since you don't know L, repeatedly double your
> guess of L until you know the optimal length is between L and 2L. Then
> use binary search to find the exactly length.

What I don't understand is the last part.

> Since you don't know L, repeatedly double your guess of L until you
> know the optimal length is between L and 2L.

How do I know what's the "optimal" length?

P.S.: The question of longest palindromic substring has been asked before, but the only one that seems to be useful is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17217473/839733), and it too doesn't use Rabin-Karp.

**Edit**:
This is the code I came up with based on the answers received.

```
public static String longestPalindrome(String key) {
    int r = 256;
    long q = longRandomPrime();
    boolean lastFound;
    boolean found;
    int l = 2;

    do {
        lastFound = indexOfPalindromeOfGivenLength(key, l, r, q) >= 0;
        l *= 2;
        found = indexOfPalindromeOfGivenLength(key, l, r, q) >= 0;
    } while (l < key.length() && !(lastFound && !found));

    int left = l / 2;
    int right = l;

    while (left <= right) {
        System.out.printf("Searching for palindromes with length between: %d and %d%n", left, right);

        int i = indexOfPalindromeOfGivenLength(key, left, r, q);
        lastFound = i >= 0;
        int j = indexOfPalindromeOfGivenLength(key, right, r, q);
        found = j >= 0;

        if (lastFound && found) return key.substring(j, j + right);

        int x = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (!found) right = x;
        else left = x;
    }

    return null;
}

private static int indexOfPalindromeOfGivenLength(String key, int l, int r, long q) {
    System.out.printf("Searching for palindromes with length: %d%n", l);

    for (int i = 0; i + l <= key.length(); i++) {
        String s1 = key.substring(i, i + l);
        long h1 = hash(s1, r, q);
        long h2 = hash(new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString(), r, q);

        if (h1 == h2) {
            System.out.printf("Found palindrome: %s of length: %d%n", s1, s1.length());
            return i;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("No palindromes of length %d exist%n", l);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You search for a palindromic substring of length L, doubling L each time until your search fails. Then you know the real answer is somewhere between the failed length and the last successful length. You use binary search to find it.

Comment: @n.m. See my comment below, or the code above. Does the termination condition make sense?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you reach `L` for which there is a palindromic substring of length `L` and no palindromic substring of length `2L`, you know that optimal length is between `L` and `2L`.

Two find it you use binary search. First try `L + ceil(L/2)` if there is palindromic substring of this length do the same with `L + ceil(L/2)` and `2L`, similarly if if there is no palindromic substring of this length, then search in `[L, L + ceil(L/2))`.

Comment: See my edit. You didn't mention the terminating condition for the binary search, but after some thought, it occurred to me that the search should terminate when both boundaries return palindromes. For example, using string `forgeeksskeegfor`, a palindrome of length `8` exists (`eeksskee`), as well as one of length `10` (`geeksskeeg`). The search terminates and returns `geeksskeeg` as the longest palindrome.