# Can Machine Learning help classify data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a data set as below,

**Code  | Description**

AB123   |   Cell Phone

B467A   |   Mobile Phone

12345   |   Telephone

WP9876  |   Wireless Phone

SP7654  |   Satellite Phone

SV7608  |   Sedan Vehicle

CC6543  |   Car Coupe

Need to create a automated grouping based on the Code and Description. Lets assume I have so many such data already classified into 0-99 groups. Whenever a new data comes in with a Code and Description, the Machine Learning algorithm needs to automatically classify this based on the previously available data.

**Code  | Description**  | **Group**

AB123   |   Cell Phone   |     1

B467A   |   Mobile Phone |     1

12345   |   Telephone    |     1

WP9876  |   Wireless Phone |     1

SP7654  |   Satellite Phone |     1

SV7608  |   Sedan Vehicle |     2

CC6543  |   Car Coupe |     3

Can this be achieved to some level of accuracy? Currently this process is so manual. Any such ideas or references are there, please help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading up on Supervised Learning.  You need to provide labels for your training data so that the algorithms know what are the correct answers - and are able to generate appropriate models for you.

Then you can "predict" the output classes for your new incoming data using the generated model(s).

Finally, you may wish to circle back to check the accuracy of the predicted results. If you then enter the labels for the newly received and predicted data then those data can then be used for further training on your model(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with supervised learning. You pick yourself a model which you "train" with the data you already have. The model/algorithm then "generalizes" to previously unseen data from the known data.

What you specify as a group would be called class or "label" which needs to be predicted based on 2 input features (code/description). Whether you input these features directly or preprocess them into more abstract features which suits the algorithm better, depends on which algorithm you choose.

If you have no experience with Machine Learning, you might start with learning some basics while testing already implemented algorithms in tools such as RapidMiner, Weka or Orange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think machine learning methods are the most appropriate for the solution of the problem, because text based machine learning algorithms tend to be quite complicated. From the examples you provided I'm not sure how

I think the simplest way of solving, or attempting to solve this problem is the following, which can be implemented in many free programming languages, such as python. Each description can be stored as a string. What you could do is to store all the substrings of all the strings (ie Phone is your string, the substrings will be 'P','h',Ph',..,'e') that belong in a particular group in a list (see this question for how to implement it in python... [Substrings of a string using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945029/substrings-of-a-string)). Then you want to for each substring and all substrings stored, see which ones are unique to a certain group. Then select strings over a certain length (say 3 characters long, to get rid of random letter concatenations) as your classification criteria. Then when you get new data, check whether the description is unique to a certain group. With this for instance, you would be able to classify all objects that are in group 1 based on whether their description contains the word phone.

Its hard to provide concrete code to solves your problem without knowing what languages you are familiar with/are feasible to use. I hope this helps anyway. Yves