# Python: Get all combinations of sequential elements of list

Tags: python, python-itertools

Given an array say `x = ['A','I','R']`
I would want output as an

```
[['A','I','R'],['A','I'],['I','R'],['A'],['I'],['R']]
```

What I don't want as output is :

```
[['A','I','R'],['A','I'],['I','R'],['A','R'],['A'],['I'],['R']]  # extra ['A','R'] which is not in sequence .
```

Below is the code which gives the output I don't want:

```
letter_list = [a for a in str]
all_word = []
for i in xrange(0,len(letter_list)):
    all_word = all_word + (map(list, itertools.combinations(letter_list,i))) # dont use append. gives wrong result.
all_word = filter(None,all_word) # remove empty combination
all_word = all_word + [letter_list] # add original list
```

My point is I only want combinations of sequences. Is there any way to use `itertools` or should I write custom function ?

Comment: A possible duplicate is here: [Substrings of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945029/substrings-of-a-string)

Comment: Do note the exponential memory usage as explained in [my answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106273/78136) to your [follow up question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106273/78136) at Code Review SE. For a text of length 1000 characters, this will require 167167000 characters when split like this, with a memory footprint of 1.25GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `itertools`:

```
>>> x = ['A', 'I', 'R']
>>> xs = [x[i:j] for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(x)+1), 2)]
>>> xs
[['A'], ['A', 'I'], ['A', 'I', 'R'], ['I'], ['I', 'R'], ['R']]
>>> sorted(xs, key=len, reverse=True)
[['A', 'I', 'R'], ['A', 'I'], ['I', 'R'], ['A'], ['I'], ['R']]
```

Credit: [answer by hochl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945642/832230)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `yield`:

```
x = ['A','I','R']

def groupme(x):
    s = tuple(x)
    for size in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        for index in range(len(s) + 1 - size):
            yield list(x[index:index + size])

list(groupme(x))

>>> [['A'], ['I'], ['R'], ['A', 'I'], ['I', 'R'], ['A', 'I', 'R']]
```

Comment: Out of the current solution, this is the only one not using a lot of memory as it uses yield to only give you the word you want when iterating. However it still does generate 500500 different element for a test case using 1000 characters. :-D

Answer (score 0):

don't try to be so magical: two loops will do what you want; one over possible sequence starts, the inner over possible sequence lengths:

```
x = "AIR" # strings are iterables/sequences, too!
all_words = []
for begin in xrange(len(x)):
    for length in xrange(1,len(x) - begin+1):
        all_words.append(x[begin:begin+length])
```

Comment: As stated in comment above, this is really memory intensive when the text input consist of more than a few hundred characters.

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension:

```
letters=['A', 'I', 'R']
[letters[start:end+1] 
 for start in xrange(len(letters)) 
 for end in xrange(start, len(letters))]

[['A'], ['A', 'I'], ['A', 'I', 'R'], ['I'], ['I', 'R'], ['R']]
```

if it is important to have the order you proposed (from longest to shortest and when the same length by starting position) you can do instead:

```
[letters[start:start+l+1]
 for l in range(len(letters))[::-1]
 for start in xrange(len(letters)-l)]

[['A', 'I', 'R'], ['A', 'I'], ['I', 'R'], ['A'], ['I'], ['R']]
```

Just to address Holroy comment. If instead of using list comprehension you use a generator expression (just substituting external `[]` with `()`) you would get a much less memory requiring code. But in this case you must be careful of not using the result more than once or for instance not trying to use list methods (such as len, or removing elements) on the result.

Comment: As stated in comment above, this is really memory intensive when the text input consist of more than a few hundred characters.